# Accessing the host loopback from AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-networking, android-virtual-device

We have a continuous integration server as shown in the image and have build agents which are connected to a Android virtual device hosted in the emulator host.

[image: architecture]

The port of each corresponding emulator is forwarded to the build agent and from the build agent the android virtual device is connected via adb. So each build agent is connected to one virtual device.

I am trying to connect to the host loop back interface from the AVD device with the IP address 10.0.2.2 as described in [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking).

But the issue is that 10.0.2.2 is not the loop back of the build agent. Instead it is connected to the loop back on the emulator host.

Is there some way to connect it to the loop back of the build agent instead of the emulator host from the android virtual device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to access it via `10.0.2.2`. Instead I had to use the ip address of the build agent to get it working.